# How to remove repeated rows in this Access query?

Tags: c#, vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I get rid of duplicated rows in my MS access query?

```
SELECT pt.code,
resis.resis,
sense.sense
FROM (sense INNER JOIN pt ON sense.code = pt.code)
INNER JOIN resis ON pt.code = resis.code;
```

Comment: Show the code, don't post links.

Comment: SELECT pt.code, resis.resis, sense.sense
FROM (sense INNER JOIN pt ON sense.code = pt.code) INNER JOIN resis ON pt.code = resis.code;

Comment: Have you tried : `SELECT DISTINCT pt.code, resis.resis, sense.sense FROM (sense INNER JOIN pt ON sense.code = pt.code) INNER JOIN resis ON pt.code = resis.code;`